# Where is events.js? (node.js debugging)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I'm trying to do a little debugging with node.js, but the stack trace is leading me into a weird file called events.js. (no path is provided)
What is that file? Where can I find it?

```
Trace: Test
    at Socket.socket.on (C:\test\SocketTest\server.js:11:13)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.onevent (C:\test\SocketTest\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:335:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (C:\test\SocketTest\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:295:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (C:\test\SocketTest\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (C:\test\SocketTest\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (C:\test\SocketTest\node_modules\socket.io-parser\index.js:247:12)
    at Client.ondata (C:\test\SocketTest\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:175:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

Comment: That's a core node module.

Comment: But where is that file located? I already searched my node installation folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the `nodejs` [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules):

> **Node.js has several modules compiled into the binary.** These modules are described in greater detail elsewhere in this documentation.
>
> The core modules are defined within Node.js's source and are located in the lib/ folder.

Emphasis mine. So if you don't build `nodejs` from source code, you won't have it on your file system (hence the missing path).

Anyway, you will encounter it in most traces, but its extremely unlikely that it has anything to do with your actual problem.

Comment: Well that sucks... Also there is no actual problem. I'm just debugging to understand how a certain function of a library works internally.

Comment: If you are curious, you can just simply grab the source code of your node version, and take a look.

Comment: Well, I was hoping to put some console.logs into the code because I don't have an actual debugger.

Comment: @Forivin: Read the core docs. Specifically EventEmitter to understand how low level events work in node.js. Once you understand that you can use that knowledge to figure out how the socket.io code works. You wouldn't debug a C program down to malloc and memcpy would you?